# How to integrate a calnder in ionic 4 which should be compatible with both web and mobile?

Tags: angular, cordova, calendar, ionic4

I am trying to integrate the calendar with ionic 4.

I came across couple of packages which are compatible with only iOS and android. But I want a package which will work on web as well.

So, please let me know how can I integrate a calendar package which is compatible with web, android and iOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ion2-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar). It works on ionic 4 as well.

Check out their live demo [here](https://hsuanxyz.github.io/demo/ion2-calendar/)

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ionic4-datepicker-component/

I have used above datepicker for my PWA project in ionic. It worked fine for both web and mobile.